# how to write data of another model to the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a model order and user.

```
user - has_many: order

order - belongs_to: user
```

I want to make a check on the order form.

```
<% if current_user%>

    form where the name of the order form will be recorded from the user

 <% else%>

    regular order creation form

 <% end%>
```

the task is how to write data of another model to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the controller

for eg.

```
Class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if current_user
      # this will set the user_id field 
      # you can set additional attributes here
      @order = current_user.orders.build({attribute: value})
    else
      @order = Order.new
    end
  end
  ...
```

in view

```
= form_for @order do |f|
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)